# Where can I find the opcode numbers for the LLVM bitcode?

Tags: llvm, bytecode, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Where can I find the LLVM bytecode representation of the LLVM IR language?

Like this `<result> = add <ty> <op1>, <op2>`, but in binary form like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) incept for LLVM instead of JVM. More specifically I want the opcode numbers so I can study the bitcode on a binary level.

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the canonical source for LLVM Bit Codes is this file :

```
llvm-src/include/llvm/Bitcode/LLVMBitCodes.h
```

from the llvm source which can be found here: http://llvm.org/releases/

You may also want to look at the code in llvm-src/lib/Bitcode/Reader, which reads bitcode.

Answer (score 1):

you can find opcode numbers in include/llvm/IR/Instruction.def

https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/RELEASE_14/include/llvm/Instruction.def